# Send commands to cmd prompt using Python subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

using python 3.7

I have the following issue: I wrote a python script in which I open a cmd prompt, do some actions then I want to send some commands to that opened cmd prompt

To simplify, it looks something like:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['start','cmd','/k','dir'], shell = True, stdin= subprocess.PIPE, 
stdout = subprocess.PIPE, text = True)

"DO some actions"

input = 'date'
process.stdin.write(input)
process.communicate(input, timeout = 10)
```

All the time the script exits with exception TimeoutExpired , and in the cmd prompt i do not see command written (the input)

I looked in the documentation, but i am new with python and did not understood very well how to use the subprocess module

Thank you for the support!

Comment: Why do you start the process? What do you run there?

Comment: Two problems here: 1) by indirectly launching `cmd` via `start`, you create a command window that you have no control over; 2) since you didn't end the "date" string with a newline, you haven't actually executed a command.

Comment: Hi Balderman, 
The idea is that i have to open a .exe file and on different timmings i have to write on the opened window some commands. I simplified  the question with the example with the cmd prompt i which i first send a dir command and afte that i want to send a new command(date) to the same cmd window. I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Hi @jasonharper,
is there a way to have control on that cmd window ?

Comment: Yes, by launching `cmd` directly, rather than asking `start` to launch it for you.

Comment: @jasonharper: but then it is not an automated test. My real scenario is that i have to open some .exe files in which i have to write commands on different timings. so depending on the test, different files have to be opened, i want to do it automatically. I could open those files automatically using the subprocess but i can not send commands to them. So i tried some simple examples to understand better the subprocess module, that is why i gave the example with the opening of cmd prompt and try do send commands

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write something like `date` in another `cmd` tab, do like this:

```py
import subprocess
input = 'date'
subprocess.Popen(['start','cmd','/k','echo',input], shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, text = True)
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Hi Behdad, 
the second command input ('date') is not send to the opned command prompt. in The command prompt you see only the result of the dir command.
Also i run the code from IDE not in the cmd prompt.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it @Costi

Comment: Hi @Behdad, it is not what i want. My script will open the cmd prompt, i will do some operation and then i want to send some commands to that open cmd prompt.